# play an audio file once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there a way to play a mp3/wav file in html only once if the condition is met. I am trying to do but the mp3 file is not playing after my required condition is met..

```
<input type="text" id="question"/>
<audio src="one.mp3" id="one" preload="auto"></audio>
<input type="text" id="question1"/>
<audio src="two.mp3" id="two" preload="auto"></audio>

<script>
$("#question").blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Paris') {
   document.getElementById("one").play();
    }
});    

$("#question1").blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'France') {
   document.getElementById("two").play();
    }
});    
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have no JS error in the rest of your doc?
Have you included JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your condition is truly met, there are a few reasons why you might not be able to hear your sound play:

- **Your browser does not support the audio type.**

  - See the table [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) to find out if your browser supports your specific type of media (in this case, `MP3`).
  - Another way you can check for this is by using the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#Audio_element_with_source_element).
  - If your browser does not accept your media type, get the proper media file and add it as a `source` as shown in the [example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all).
- **The media file cannot be found.**

  - Make sure that your media file can be found by the browser.
  - You can check this by heading to the media's `src` attribute (in this case, `./one.mp3` or `./two.mp3`).
- **Your volume is silent.**

  - Although this may seem silly, a hard day of work can leave one forgetful.
  - Check that your speakers / headphones are working and that your volume is at a high level.
- **Last but not least, the file is corrupted, damaged, or contains no information.**

  - To check for this, play the media file on your laptop. Your program should let you know if the file is corrupted or damaged.
  - Check the file's size to make sure there is information in it.

Comment: I am using chrome and it supports mp3 and i checked in my laptop and the file is not damaged.

Comment: @user3622856 Are there any errors showing in Chrome's dev console?

Comment: @user3622856 BTW: Errors also include 404s. Try setting up your audio code like so:

    `<audio controls id="ID">
      <source src="NAME.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>`

And then try playing the audio (run the command through the console, not by trying to blur `#question(1)`.